# Bootstrap date picker disabled css not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I have set the `minimum date` of datepicker to the `current date`.Its working fine and i can choose dates starting only from the current date.The problem is although previous dates are disabled user cannot differentiate between the active date and disabled dates(he can do so only by hovering over the respective dates).

How can I make the disabled dates to `fade` so that user can understand merely by selecting the datepicker.

```
 $('.dueDate').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: '+0d', // set default to today's date  
        datesDisabled:??//How can I set this option         
    })
```

Comment: Hi ksg, can you provide some more info on what the exact problem is? As I can't seem to understand what you are trying to do. The example shows your code and does work: http://jsfiddle.net/zcvq0yhh/16/

Comment: Mate issue is already solved by giving the below mentioned css and I have marked the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `startDate` field to specify when you want the calendar to start, which should by default make the disabled dates look faded / unselectable.

You can also make certain days of the week disabled, like the weekends by using `daysOfWeekDisabled`.

For Example:

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
     startDate: "dateToday",
     daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
     todayHighlight: true,
 })
```

---

**Edit:**

If that isn't working, it may be an issue with your css.

You could add something like this below (which should have been in your bootstrap-datepicker3.css file by default):

```
.datepicker table tr td.disabled,
.datepicker table tr td.disabled:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #999999;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Why [`daysOfWeekDisabled`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#setdaysofweekdisabled) over [`setDatesDisabled`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#setdatesdisabled)?

Comment: Then it may be in your css why the fields aren't showing up as disabled.

Comment: @JonnyHenly either one you can use, they both do different things though. 'daysOfWeekDisabled' is for setting certain days of the week disabled every week, like weekends. 'setDatesDisabled' are for setting particular days of the year disabled, like holidays.

Comment: @Wellspring oh gotcha. Good answer, best one so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
var nowDate = new Date();
var today = new Date(
    nowDate.getFullYear(),
    nowDate.getMonth(),
    nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0
);

$('#date').datepicker(
    { 
        startDate: today 
    }
);
```

Comment: *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."* - [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: All this overhead is not necessary as `eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker` supports relative timedelta strings. See [docs](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#options)